# MYSQL - Difference between IN and EXIST

Tags: sql, mysql, database, exists

MySql question:

What is the difference between [NOT] IN and [NOT] EXIST when doing subqueries in MySql.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### EXISTS

EXISTS literally is for checking for the existence of specified criteria.  In current standard SQL, it will allow you to specify more than one criteria for comparison - IE if you want to know when col_a and col_b both match - which makes it a little stronger than the IN clause.  MySQL IN supports tuples, but the syntax is not portable, so EXISTS is a better choice both for readability and portability.

The other thing to be aware of with EXISTS is how it operates - EXISTS returns a boolean, and will return a boolean on the first match.  So if you're dealing with duplicates/multiples, EXISTS will be faster to execute than IN or JOINs depending on the data and the needs.

### IN

IN is syntactic sugar for OR clauses.  While it's very accommodating, there are issues with dealing with lots of values for that comparison (north of 1,000).

### NOT

The NOT operator just reverses the logic.

### Subqueries vs JOINs

The mantra "always use joins" is flawed, because JOINs risks inflating the result set if there is more than one child record against a parent.  Yes, you can use DISTINCT or GROUP BY to deal with this, but it's very likely this renders the performance benefit of using a JOIN moot.  Know your data, and what you want for a result set - these are key to writing SQL that performs well.

To reiterate knowing when and why to know what to use - LEFT JOIN IS NULL is the fastest exclusion list on MySQL ***if the columns compared are NOT nullable***, otherwise NOT IN/NOT EXISTS are better choices.

Reference:

- [MySQL: LEFT JOIN/IS NULL, NOT IN, NOT EXISTS on nullable columns](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)
- [MySQL: LEFT JOIN/IS NULL, NOT IN, NOT EXISTS on NOT nullable columns](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Answer (score 3):

They work very differently:

- EXISTS takes a single argument which should be a subquery (derived table) and checks if there is at least one row returned by the subquery.
- IN takes two arguments, the first of which should be a single value (or a tuple), and the second of which is a subquery or a tuple and checks if the first value is contained in second.

However both can be used to check if a row in table A has a matching row in table B. Unless you are careful and know what you are doing I would stay clear of IN in MySQL as it often gives much poorer performance on more complex queries. Use NOT EXISTS or a LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL.