# Howto split up multiple joins and conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I want to display a list of all projects, where a project

- has one or more tasks

  AND
- has one or more clients OR has flag 'can_have_clients = 0'

  AND
- current_user has assignment on client

My current query is working, but does not look like the right way:

```
Project.where('id IN (SELECT DISTINCT project_id FROM tasks)')
       .where('id IN (SELECT DISTINCT project_id FROM clients WHERE id IN (
                        SELECT DISTINCT resource_id FROM assignments WHERE resource_type="Client" AND user_id=?)) 
               OR can_have_clients = 0', current_user)
```

Is it possible to split up more (specially the last where/OR) and does this look like the way to go with rails?

```
# model
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :clients
  ...
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  ...
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, :as => :resource
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Project.joins(:tasks).joins( :clients => :assignments).where(
  :projects    => { :can_have_clients => 0},
  :assignments => { :resource_type => "Client",  :user_id => current_user}
).select("DISTINCT project.*")
```

If you want to eager load tasks and clients and assignments:

```
Project.include(:tasks).include( :clients => :assignments).
  where("tasks.id IS NOT NULL AND clients.id IS NOT NULL AND 
    assignments.id IS NOT NULL").
  where(
    :projects    => { :can_have_clients => 0},
    :assignments => { :resource_type => "Client",  :user_id => current_user}
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [named_scope](http://www.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html) here to optimize your query in rails format .

And for performance vice you can make the query like :

```
Project.where('exists (SELECT 1 FROM tasks where tasks.project_id=project.id)')
       .where('exists (SELECT 1 FROM clients WHERE exists (
                        SELECT 1 FROM assignments WHERE assignments.resource_id=clients.id AND resource_type="Client" AND user_id=?)) 
               OR can_have_clients = 0', current_user)
```

because in is too costly than exists , [check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999600/mysql-difference-between-in-and-exist).