# Create view (Exists or in)

Tags: mysql

Create a view consisting of the names of all customers who have a loan and an account at the Perryridge branch.

Any ideas on this? I am confused whether or not to use exists or in

---

The tables are:

```
customer (customer_name, customer_street, customer_city)
  depositor (customer_name, account_number)
    account (account_number, branch_name, balance)
  borrower (customer_name, loan_number)
    loan (loan_number, branch_name, amount)
```

Comment: A view is basicly the result of a select. Once you have figured out what the select should be, you can have the view. I don't understand fully what you mean by "to use exists or in"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999600/mysql-difference-between-in-and-exist

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question.  I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either an `EXISTS` or an `IN` predicate in your query. Either will work.

(A "view" is essentially a query. So the question is really, first, about formulating a query that returns a specified resultset. Once you have a query, it's a simple matter of wrapping that in a CREATE VIEW statement. I will note here that we do not normally use views in a MySQL database. This is because of the way the MySQL optimizer works, it always materializes a view query into a derived table, which differs from the way view queries are handled in other DBMS.)

Assuming that you have separate tables for `customer`, `account` and/or `loan`, you will likely need `EXISTS` predicates, `IN` predicates, or join operations, or some combination of those.

As an example, this query (below) uses `EXISTS` predicates to test for the existence of matching rows in both the `account` table and the `loan` tables, and returns rows from `customer` that have at least one associated account at the Perryridge branch, and at least one associated loan.

```
SELECT c.name
  FROM customer c
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                  FROM account a
                 WHERE a.customer_id = c.id 
                   AND a.branch = 'Perryridge' 
              )
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                  FROM loan l
                 WHERE l.customer_id = c.id
              )
```

---

This query (below) returns an equivalent resultset, but uses `IN` predicates to look for the matching rows in the account and loan tables:

```
SELECT c.name
  FROM customer c
 WHERE c.id IN ( SELECT a.customer_id
                   FROM account a
                  WHERE a.branch = 'Perryridge'
               )
   AND c.id IN ( SELECT l.customer_id
                  FROM loan l
               )
```

And this query (below) makes use of JOIN operations to look for matching rows. The behavior of the JOIN is different than the queries above, in that it will return multiple copies of the customer row, if there is more than one account at the Perryridge branch, or more than one loan.  We can easily eliminate those duplicates by including a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT c.name
  FROM customer c
  JOIN account a
    ON a.customer_id = c.id
   AND a.branch = 'Perryridge'
  JOIN loan l
    ON l.customer_id = c.id
 GROUP BY c.id
```

---

Absent any information about your schema, I've made some assumptions here that the column `id` is the primary key of the `customer` table, and that both the `account` and `loan` tables each have a foreign key `customer_id` that reference `customer(id)`, etc.

Each of these queries will exhibit different performance characteristics. All the queries will likely benefit from indexes

```
... ON account (customer_id, branch)
... ON loan (customer_id)
... ON customer (id, name)
```

This should be sufficient to answer your question.

---

**UPDATE:**

Given (by Billy)

```
branch(branch_name, branch_city, assets) 
customer(customer_name, customer_street, customer_city)
account(account_number, branch_name, balance)
loan(loan_number, branch_name, amount)
depositor(customer_name, account_number)
borrower(customer_name, loan_number)
```

(This seems WAY more like an academic homework or test problem than it does a database designed and implemented by IT professionals.)

Get names of customers (`depositor`) who have an `account` at 'Perryridge' branch:

```
SELECT d.customer_name
  FROM depositor d
  JOIN account a
    ON a.account_number = d.account_number
 WHERE a.branch_name = 'Perryridge'
 GROUP BY d.customer_name
```

Get names of customers (`borrower`) who have a `loan` at 'Perryridge' branch:

```
SELECT b.customer_name
  FROM borrower b
  JOIN loan l
    ON l.loan_number = b.loan_number
   AND l.branch_name = 'Perryridge'
 GROUP BY b.customer_name
```

(If we need additional columns from the `customer` table, we would add a JOIN to that table:

```
SELECT c.customer_name
     , c.customer_street
     , c.customer_city
  FROM customer c
  JOIN borrower b
    ON b.customer_name = c.customer_name
  JOIN loan l
    ON l.loan_number = b.loan_number
   AND l.branch_name = 'Perryridge'
 GROUP
    BY c.customer_name
     , c.customer_street
     , c.customer_city
```

Get names of customers who have both a deposit account (`depositor`) and a loan (`borrower`) at 'Perryridge' branch:

```
SELECT c.customer_name
     , c.customer_street
     , c.customer_city
  FROM customer c
  JOIN borrower b
    ON b.customer_name = c.customer_name
  JOIN loan l
    ON l.loan_number = b.loan_number
   AND l.branch_name = 'Perryridge'
  JOIN depositor d
    ON d.customer_name = c.customer_name
  JOIN account a
    ON a.account_number = d.account_number
   AND a.branch_name = 'Perryridge'
 GROUP
    BY c.customer_name
     , c.customer_street
     , c.customer_city
 ORDER
    BY c.customer_name
     , c.customer_street
     , c.customer_city
```

An almost identical result set can be returned with a query that uses EXISTS predicates with correlated subqueries.  (The difference is that the JOIN query above can introduce "duplicates", when a customer has more than one account or more than one loan at Perryridge. The GROUP BY clause there eliminates the duplicates.)

```
SELECT c.customer_name
     , c.customer_street
     , c.customer_city
  FROM customer c
 WHERE EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM borrower b
          WHERE b.customer_name = c.customer_name
            AND EXISTS
                ( SELECT 1
                    FROM loan l
                   WHERE l.loan_number = b.loan_number
                      AND l.branch_name = 'Perryridge'
                )
       )
   AND EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM depositor d
          WHERE d.customer_name = c.customer_name
            AND EXISTS
                ( SELECT 1
                    FROM account a
                   WHERE a.account_number = d.account_number
                     AND a.branch_name = 'Perryridge'
                )
       )
 ORDER
    BY c.customer_name
     , c.customer_street
     , c.customer_city
```

This query won't introduce any duplicates, in that it's only returning rows from the `customer` table. (The only way this query will return duplicates is if there are duplicate rows in the `customer` table.) If there are no duplicate rows in the `customer` table, then the GROUP BY is not necessary.

Comment: branch(branch_name, branch_city, assets) customer(customer_name, customer_street, customer_city) account(account_number, branch_name, balance) loan(loan_number, branch_name, amount) depositor(customer_name, account_number) borrower(customer_name, loan_number)

Comment: @Billy, this information might really better be included in your question, rather than as a comment on my answer.