# Mysql EXISTS vs IN slow performance

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have `posts` and `websites` (and connecting `post_websites`). Each `post` can be on multiple `websites`, and some `websites` share the content, so I am trying to access the `posts` which are attached to particular `website` IDs.

Most of the cases `WHERE IN` works fine, but not for all `websites`, some of them are laggy, and I can't understand a difference.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE `posts`.`id` IN (
    SELECT `post_websites`.`post_id`
    FROM `post_websites`
    WHERE `website_id` IN (
        12054,
        19829,
        2258,
        253
    )
) AND
    `status` = 1 AND
    `posts`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY `post_date` DESC
LIMIT 6
```

##### Explain

| select_type | table | type | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SIMPLE | post_websites | range | post_websites_website_id_index | 4 | NULL | 440 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort; Start temporary |
| SIMPLE | posts | eq_ref | PRIMARY | 4 | post_websites.post_id | 1 | Using where; End temporary |

Other version with `EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT `post_websites`.`post_id`
    FROM `post_websites`
    WHERE `website_id` IN (
        12054,
        19829,
        2258,
        253
    ) AND
    `posts`.`id` = `post_websites`.`post_id`
) AND
    `status` = 1 AND
    `deleted_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY `post_date` DESC
LIMIT 6
```

##### EXPLAIN:

| select_type | table | type | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PRIMARY | posts | index | post_date_index | 5 | NULL | 12 | Using where |
| DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | post_websites | ref | post_id_website_id_unique | 4 | post.id | 1 | Using where; Using index |

Long story short: based on different amounts of `posts` on each site and amount of `websites` sharing content the results are different from `20ms` to `50s`!

Based on the `EXPLAIN` the `EXISTS` works better, but on practice when the amount of data in subquery is lower, it can be very slow.

Is there a query I am missing that could work like a charm for all cases? Or should I check something before querying and choose the method of doing so dynamically?

migrations:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(225) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `posts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `created_at_index` (`created_at`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `status_deleted_at_index` (`status`,`deleted_at`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `post_date_index` (`post_date`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `id_post_date_status_deleted_at` (`id`,`post_date`,`status`,`deleted_at`) USING BTREE;


CREATE TABLE `post_websites` (
  `post_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `website_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE `post_websites`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`website_id`, `post_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `post_id_website_id_unique` (`post_id`,`website_id`),
  ADD KEY `website_id_index` (`website_id`),
  ADD KEY `post_id_index` (`post_id`);
```

eloquent:

```
$news = Post::select(['title', 'description'])
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->whereExists(
                function ($query) use ($sites) {
                    $query->select('post_websites.post_id')
                        ->from('post_websites')
                        ->whereIn('websites_id', $sites)
                        ->whereRaw('post_websites.post_id = posts.id');
            })
            ->orderBy('post_date', 'desc');
            ->limit(6)
            ->get();

or 
$q->whereIn('posts.id',
                function ($query) use ($sites) {
                    $query->select('post_websites.post_id')
                        ->from('post_websites')
                        ->whereIn('website_id', $sites);
                });
```

Thanks.

Comment: try an inner join with big IN or EXISTS

Comment: is there a universal solution for big or small data in subquery? I don't know how big is the data unless I query that separately first.

Comment: INNEr JOIN is faster with big data, with smal numbers you get almost te same, but mysqlget diffrent ways. itry it

Comment: just tried, same story, some websites are flying, for some this query goes for 4 secods.

Comment: Have you tried the query using equivalent Eloquent relationships and query builder methods to see if you can accomplish this more easily and effectively that way?

Comment: yes it's all encoded in eloquent methods, just showing the mysql problem on resulted query.

Comment: @JackBo can you show us both Eloquent queries instead of SQL queries so it is more readable ? I had to work with reports and before upgrading our eloquent queries we were having like `4s` latency response, and after fixing some performant stuff (like yours) we went down to `100ms` without the need of a special query for a special case or anything like that... Also, can you share your migrations for these tables ? I think you are not `indexing` some IDs.

Comment: @matiaslauriti added migrations and Eloquent code. I do see what this answer mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172487/why-sql-with-exists-run-slower-than-in-using-mysql. My EXISTS works when there a lot of overlapping, sites share content and posts share them, for example I have blog posted on site A and B, and at the same time site A and B selected to share content , if there are a lot of these, then WHERE IN choke, but EXISTS performs well. But when there are not a lot of content and it's not overlapping then WHERE IN is much better. EXISTS more than a minute sometimes...

Comment: Actually not a lot of overlapping also lags for WHERE IN, 5929 results , only 2 duplicate and it process 6 seconds.

Comment: @JackBo why are you literally using a query instead of relations to accomplish this ? Why are you not using [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) ? Also, could you share the real migration (`PHP`) file ? Plain SQL is it not as readable as a PHP migration. Could you replace that?

Comment: @matiaslauriti We found it is faster because post_websites doesn't have model it's a pivot, only POST and WEBSITE has models, when you do whereHas('website'), i believe it also gets info from website table, which we don't need in this case.

Comment: @JackBo I can't remember 100% right now what will happen, but if you have a relation `many-to-many` it will ask the pivot table (you do not need to have a model for the pivot), so my personal recommendation would be to either try `whereHas` or [`whereRelation`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inline-relationship-existence-queries) (if this last one still works for your conditions) and see if it works better. Also, remember that you can see the final result using `->toSql()` at the end instead of `->get()` so you can see the real SQL run. Can you try that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236788/discussion-between-jack-bo-and-matiaslauriti).

Answer (score 0):

Many:many table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
That says to get rid if `id` (because it slows things down), promote that `UNIQUE` to be the PK, and add an `INDEX` in the opposite direction.

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  A simple `JOIN` is probably the best alternative here.

Did some 3rd party package provide those 3 `TIMESTAMPs` for each table?  Are they ever used?  Get rid of them.

```
KEY `id_post_date_status_deleted_at` (`id`,`post_date`,`status`,`deleted_at`) USING BTREE;
```

is mostly backward.  Some rules:

- Don't start an index with the `PRIMARY KEY` column(s).
- Do start an index with `=` tests: `status`,`deleted_at`

Comment: Simplified connecting table to only have posts_id and website_id.
Doesn't change the situation