# Find orders that have more than just a specific SKU

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a SQL query that will return all order numbers that have more than just `SKU` `ENROLL` but should not return an order number where `SKU` `ENROLL` is the only `SKU` on the order.

In this example, this order would be included in the query results. 
Order `1001`, contains `SKU` `ENROLL` and `SKU` `688631`.

In this example, this order would **NOT** be included in the query results.
Order `1003`, contains `SKU` `ENROLL`

Important to note, when query results are returned they look like this

[image]

Here is what I've written thus far but I am not sure on the rest. I've taken feedback from everyone who has responded and tried to incorporate it but haven't had good results.

select VO.DistID, VO.FirstName, VO.LastName, VO.OrderNumber, Email, Quantity, Sku, OrderStatus FROM dbo.VwOrders AS VO INNER JOIN dbo.VwDistributor AS VD ON VO.DistID = VD.DistID INNER JOIN dbo.VwOrderLines AS VOL ON VO.OrderNumber = VOL.OrderNumber INNER JOIN dbo.VwInventory AS VI ON vol.ItemNumber = VI.InventoryNo AND VOL.Warehouse = VI.Warehouse WHERE Sku = 'ENROLL'

Comment: And what have you tried so far?  We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: Have you looked into the DISTINCT keyword yet?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to do this.  Here's one option using conditional aggregation:

```
select orderid
from yourtable
group by orderid
having max(case when sku = 'ENROLL' then 1 else 0 end) = 1  
   and max(case when sku != 'ENROLL' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44e08/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
select OrderID from table where SKU = 'ENROLL' and OrderID in 
(select distinct OrderID from table group by OrderID having count(*) > 1)
```

Explanation: the inner query will give you all orderId's that appears more than once in the table. what we do in the rest of the query is select all records that equals to 'enroll' + in the appear twice list

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` subqueries:

```
select *
from tbl t
where exists (select 1 from tbl x where x.orderid = t.orderid and x.sku = 'ENROLL')
  and exists (select 1 from tbl x where x.orderid = t.orderid and x.sku <> 'ENROLL');
```

Comment: What are the benefit of `exists` vs `IN`?

Comment: Functionally it is the same. In MySQL `exists` might be faster depending on the number of rows on the table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999600/mysql-difference-between-in-and-exist In other databases I would imagine the optimizer would decide behind the scenes how to run the query regardless of which was used

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting answers so far. I really enjoyed reading them. Here is one option from me.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE SKU = 'ENROLL') t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE SKU != 'ENROLL') t2
ON t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID
GROUP BY t1.OrderID
```

I build two tables one having all order with at least one SKU = 'ENROLL' and one for orders with at least one SKU different from 'ENROLL' and I join them to get ... well the cross section of them two. This is what you look for, right?

Comment: it will work, but I'm not sure how good the performance is going to be for this one. you have two inner queries and also join, not sure it's the optimal way